# Publish MVC 5 on IIS server without azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

Is there a way to publish my MVC web app on my IIS server the same way i was doing it in classic ASP.NET 2010. I mean, i don't really need azure because i have this an IIS server up and running, i'm searching for that king of window :

[image]

But i'm stucked with this :

[image]

And i've been wondering what do i put in `Server :` to make this thing work... usualy i don't specify it since i have a cennected drive...

Comment: don't you want publish local and then just copy files to your server?

Comment: Yeah could work, but i'd like to be able to publish without having to copy the files every time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply a server's hostname.

You have selected the FTP as a publishing method. General format for FTP URL is:

```
ftp://username:password@host
```

It's the same as if you want to open a web page in your browser using HTTP protocol. You simply have to enter a hostname or FQDN, it can't work without that.

`Host` can be just a hostname (if it's in the same network as your client) or an FQDN, if it's accessible through the internet (like for example `ftp.example.com`).